# Bootstrap nesting a dropdown inside of another dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to nest a dropdown inside of another dropdown ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj3k550m/1/)):

[image]

However, the nested dropdown closes the parent dropdown when you try to open it. After an hour of research, I tried adding `e.stopPropagation()` as suggested by some answers on SO to no avail. How can I properly nest one dropdown inside of another?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-info" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 1</a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 10px;min-width:500px;">

        <div class="tab-container tab-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs flat-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" style="border: 0;">
                <div class="tab-pane active cont fade in" id="1">

                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Dropdown
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane cont fade" id="2">
                    <h3 class="hthin">Test Page 2</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling, the solution was to manually open and close the dropdown. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj3k550m/3/).

```
$('.testLinkOpen').on('click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('.parentContainer').is(e.target) && $('.parentContainer').has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('.parentContainer').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```